# How did imprisoned Azazel end up on some woman's bedside table?

Tags: vertigo-comics, the-sandman, lucifer

If my memory servers me right, Azazel was imprisoned by the Dream of the Endless, after it (he?she? do floating eyes and maws have gender?) tried to blackmail Morpheus.

[image]

Then in the #2 issue of *Lucifer* (2016) it sits politely near the bed of some relatively normal woman named Teena Hornick, or to be precise near the bed that used to belong to her recently deceased parents (Teena is doing after-funeral cleanup).

[image]

Narrator <sup>*</sup> mentions that Teena's parents were bit of a hoarders, always looking for a "bargain" on flea markets, but how ones accidentally purchases one of the major demons (in a jar)? Has this been addressed in some other comic books (Hellblazer maybe)?

> <sup>The narrator is of course the omnipresent Elaine Belloc</sup>